# remove the Box around a figure

Tags: floats

I need to include figures in my document and i use the following code for that

```
\begin{figure}[h]  
    \centering  
    \includegraphics{QApic}  
    \caption{Figure One}  
    \label{QApic}  
\end{figure}
```

The figure appears with a black box around it. How can i modify so that the figure appears with no box around it?

Below is the entire structure

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs} %runningheads adds headers with page numbers
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed}
\restylefloat{figure}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}

\lstdefinestyle{myjava}{language=Java}
\lstset{style=myjava}

\title{Evaluation of xyz}
\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}

%\tableofcontents

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Introduction}

\begin{figure}[h]  
    \centering  
    \includegraphics{QApic}  
    \caption{Figure One}  
    \label{QApic}  
\end{figure}

\section{Experiment}

\section{conclusion}

\end{document}
```

Comment: by default the above would produce no box. so any box is produced by code you have not shown.

Comment: I am using lncs package. could that be the reason?
if so can i change that?

Comment: Please provide a MWE.

Comment: If you mean the `llncs` class, then that class produces no black border either. Either you are loading more packages (with `\usepackage{…}`), or your figure already has a black border. Check that by opening it in another image viewer or editor.

Comment: \documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed}
\restylefloat{figure}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lipsum}

Comment: These are the packages I am using.  and no it is a self-drawn graph there is  no box in the original picture

Comment: @Alina, please update your question with the information, and make sure it is a full example that others can use as is, without having to add or change anything.

Comment: @Alina perhaps this one: `\floatstyle{boxed}`

Comment: @daleif. Thanks removing that line helped remove the box :)

Comment: I have one more question... 
when i use 
\begin{figure}[h] 
all figures appear at the end of the document and not where the code is used. and when using
\begin{figure}[p] 
an entire page is being used for the figure alone with a lot of blank spaces. 
is there any option to make the figure appear at the specified position without lot of white spaces?

Comment: @Alina `\begin{figure}[htp]`

Comment: `[h]` means do not put the float at the top of the page, the bottom of a page, or an a page of floats (as no `t`, `b` or `p`) so it gives latex almost no chance to place the figure so going to the end is quite likely. latex gives a warning and changes it to `ht` but even that is very restrictive.

Comment: what did you intend `\floatstyle{boxed}` to do, if not draw a box?

Comment: Only for equations

Comment: @Alina equations does not belong in floats

Comment: @daleif Would you like to answer, or close?

Comment: got the answer. can close.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a misunderstanding of the way equations and floats relate.